# Laravel 5.4 S3 Bucket Image Upload Issue

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5.4

I get below issue while upload file using s3 bucket.

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Missing required client configuration options: 

My S3 Array in config/filesystems.php file

's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env("S3_KEY",'mykey'),
            'secret' => env("S3_SECRET",'my_secret'),
            'region' => env("S3_REGION",'my_region'),
            'bucket' => env("S3_BUCKET",'my_bucket')
        ],
```

I think issue is in Above s3 array. please let me correct.

Comment: have you tried "artisan config cache" in that case?

Comment: @RohitS, Thanks. issue gone but there is again another issue "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455410/error-executing-putobject-on-aws-upload-fails" . I am working on it.

Comment: @RohitS,  sorry to late but issue resolved same day. Thanks