# Laravel 5 upload files to s3 on wrong url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I implements uploads files to s3 in Laravel 5, when upload file it give error message: Error executing \"PutObject\" on ......, I found it happen because the url try to access is wrong, the url is :

```
https://{buckets}.{s3 domain}/{buckets}/{filename}
```

, before s3 domain why laravel put buckets name on url? the correct url should be

```
https://{s3 domain}/{buckets}/{filename}
```

, so how to fix it?

the following is my code:

```
>     $file = $request->file('file');
>     $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
>     $savedFileName = '/test_buckets/' . date('YmdHis') . '_' . $fileName;
>     $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
>     $s3->put($savedFileName, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to generate URL.

Comment: Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098327/1227923)

Comment: the permission setting is good, the error is url is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by remove 'public' from $s3->put($savedFileName, file_get_contents($file), 'public'), it looks like bug -- when have the optional third parameter 'public', it will add bukets name before domain name in url.