# Laravel backup with spatie/laravel-backup - There is no disk set for the backup destination - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: laravel

I'm unable to backup to GCS from Laravel app
using [spatie/laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup)

```
$ php artisan backup:run
Starting backup...
Dumping database reviewbooster...
Determining files to backup...
Zipping 720 files...
Created zip containing 720 files. Size is 29.86 MB
Copying zip to disk named gcs...

Copying zip failed because: There is no disk set for the backup destination. 

Backup completed!
```

filesystems.php

```
'gcs' => [
            'driver' => 'gcs',
            'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'project-id'),
            'key_file' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
            'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'bucket'),
            'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', null), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
            'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
            'visibility' => 'private', // optional: public|private
        ],
```

backup.php

```
 'destination' => [

            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => '',

            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'gcs',
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Make sure you have cleared cache after update `config` file using `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Yes I did. But still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem.

For me, the root cause was that my `.env` file had incorrect variables names that didn't match what Laravel expected in `config/filesystems.php`.

For example, I had:

```
AWS_KEY=xxx
AWS_SECRET=xxx
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=xxx
```

instead of:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=xxx
```

---

P.S. Once I fixed that, I tried running the backup again and got a new error (403 Forbidden, Access Denied, Error executing "PutObject").

So then I visited https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users/ and clicked "Add inline policy" for the relevant user. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098327/470749).)