# S3 error access when upgrading AWS PHP SDK versions

Tags: php, aws-php-sdk

I'm upgrading a system that uses `aws-php-sdk v2` to `aws-php-sdk v3`.

In `v2` i have something like:

```
$this->s3->upload($bucket, $key, $file, 'public-read');
//Where $this->s3 is a S3Client instance (from the SDK).
```

And it works well.

Now, after upgrading to `aws-php-sdk v3`, it throws an error:

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/folder/file.ext".
>
> Client error: `PUT https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/folder/file.ext` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response
>
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Im using the same accessKey and secret that i used in `v2` system.

As far as i know, is the PHP SDK that is responsible for signature calculation.. As i'm not doing any calculations manually.

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Have a look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455410/error-executing-putobject-on-aws-upload-fails) Maybe it helps you.

Comment: This  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455410/error-executing-putobject-on-aws-upload-fails) works for me.

Comment: @Refilon Just readed that question. i tried to read the bucket list with `$buckets = $this->s3->listBuckets();
        foreach ($buckets['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
            echo $bucket['Name'] . "\n";
        }` and it worked, it echoes the buckets available... so is not a problem with key or secret

Comment: @AshiqurRahman your link is equal to Refilon link... any other idea?

Comment: @Pipe 403 Forbidden errors with AWS are most likely to be 1) a problem with rights and policies 2) trying to access a non-existent folder. Can you be absolutely sure that it does not have to do with one of those?

Comment: @Pipe, would it be possible to get the exact version of the SDK you are using? Looking over [the `.changes/3.52.22` file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/.changes/3.52.22) in [the AWS PHP SDK GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php), it seems that there was a bug fix in SDK version 3.52.22 which addressed a bug that was causing invalid signatures for S3 operations. I am just curious if you might be using a version that does not include that fix.

Comment: @SpencerD, i was using `v3.96.0`, just upgraded to `v3.101.0` and got the same error

Comment: Just found the solution. I just posted it as an answer. FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer to my problem.

The problem was: in `aws-php-sdk v2` I had this code:

```
$bucket = "mybucketname/myfolder";
$key = "myfilename.jpg";
$upload = $this->app->S3->upload($bucket, $key, fopen( $local , 'rb'), 'public-read');
```

This works well and it not shows any warnings/errors, but when upgrading to `aws-php-sdk v3` it doesn't work.
I just changed the `$bucket` and the `$key` values as:

```
$bucket = "mybucketname";
$key = "myfolder/myfilename.jpg";
$upload = $this->app->S3->upload($bucket, $key, fopen( $local , 'rb'), 'public-read');
```

And it just worked!

Its really weird that it doesnt complain in `v2` but in `v3`.